# What does the *.*;auth,authpriv.none -/var/log/syslog line mean in rsyslog config file?

Tags: debian, rsyslog

I'm trying to understand the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, but I'm missing something. For example, this is a part of the file:

```
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
cron.*              /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log
```

According to [this](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) page:

> The facility is one of the following keywords: auth, authpriv, cron,
>   daemon, kern, lpr, mail, mark, news, security (same as auth), syslog,
>   user, uucp and local0 through local7.
>
> The priority is one of the following keywords, in ascending order:
>   debug,info, notice, warning, warn (same as warning), err, error (same
>   as err) crit, alert, emerg, panic (same as emerg). The keywords error,
>   warn and panic are deprecated and should not be used anymore. The
>   priority defines the severity of the message.
>
> An asterisk ("*") stands for all facilities or all priorities,
>   depending on where it is used (before or after the period). The
>   keyword none stands for no priority of the given facility.
>
> You can specify multiple facilities with the same priority pattern in
>   one statement using the comma (",") operator. You may specify as much
>   facilities as you want. Remember that only the facility part from such
>   a statement is taken, a priority part would be skipped.
>
> Multiple selectors may be specified for a single action using the
>   semicolon (";") separator. Remember that each selector in the
>   selector field is capable to overwrite the preceding ones. Using this
>   behavior you can exclude some priorities from the pattern.

So, this is pretty understandable but what about the file path on the right. It can be just a path, or path with `|` or `-` before it (or maybe even something else). What is the difference between the three?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

`*.*` means log all facilities and all priorities.

`auth,authpriv.none` means don't log the auth and authpriv facilities.

`-/var/log/syslog` means log to the file /var/log/syslog.  The preceding dash tells syslogd not to call fsync(), i.e. do not flush the kernel buffer to disk after every write to the file.

Comment: How does `auth,authpriv.none` mean don't log? From the quoted doc, "each selector in the selector field is capable to overwrite the preceding ones" - where is the detail of that behaviour documented? I would have expected the `auth` part to match the auth facility that had already been matched under `*.*`, rather than disabling it.

Comment: `auth,authpriv` matches both `auth` and `authpriv`.  The `.none` part applies to both of them. `*.*;auth;authpriv.none` would behave as you describe.

Comment: OK thanks! And is that documented anywhere?

Comment: It's implied in the documentation above.  The priority part is skipped (ignored) for all but the last facility if you list multiple facilities using a comma.  The docs could certainly be improved in this area.

Comment: I added the line `*.*;auth,authpriv.none          /dev/console`  so that the syslog messages also come out on the console (tty1) on my Raspberry Pi.  I have a monitor plugged into my Pi server that is used just to monitor the logs.  I ssh in to do any work on it you see.