# Dash Slash Meaning vs just Slash -/var vs /var

Tags: centos, rsyslog, syntax

Working with Centos 7

In the rsyslog.conf file there are some rules that place logs in directories that start with a -/ (Dash slash) before stating which directory to place the logs, while others have the usual / followed by the directory.

I know the slash before the directory says to start from the root directory, but what does the dash do?

Does the dash mean something specific as I cannot find the meaning behind it anywhere.

Thank you!
TDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question: [What does the *.*;auth,authpriv.none -/var/log/syslog line mean in rsyslog config file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108331/what-does-the-auth-authpriv-none-var-log-syslog-line-mean-in-rsyslog-confi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The dash means don't flush the kernel buffer to disk after every write to the file

Comment: I guess my querying skills need improvement haha, Thank you for your answer. What were your search keywords if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: I searched `rsyslog "-/"` in `google`, normally a `-` before a word will exclude results which contain that word, so you need to put the `-/` in double quotes